# Intercept Azure WebJobs queue/service bus triggers?

Tags: azure-webjobs

I'd like to be able to intercept a call to my ServiceBus triggered job, look at the message and set some thread-static context data before my job is actually triggered. Is there any way to do this with the current SDK?

Comment: Why can't you set that first thing in the function that is triggered?

Comment: I certainly can on an individual message handler level, but I have a bunch of message handlers that all need to have a context set in exactly the same way and pushing that into a common module would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't a way to do this currently. However, we're looking at adding a new feature that will allow you to do so. We've already done this for Azure Queues (see PR https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/pull/526) and we'll do something very similar for ServiceBus. Would this meet your needs?

You can see the issue in our public issues list here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/275.